# I Need To Make Page Content Min-Height 100 % But Isn't Work

Tags: css

i need to make my responsive css page content 100 % min-height ... i need help..

```
@media (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1280px) {  

    .page-boxed .header .dropdown .username {
        display: none;
    }   
}

@media (min-width: 980px) { 

    /***
    Page sidebar
    ***/
    .page-sidebar {
        position: absolute;
        width: 225px;
        min-height:100%;
    }

    .page-sidebar-fixed .page-sidebar {
        position: fixed !important;
        top: 41px;
    }

    .page-sidebar-fixed ul.page-sidebar-menu > li.last {
        margin-bottom: 15px !important;
    }

    .page-sidebar-fixed.page-sidebar-hover-on .page-sidebar {
        z-index: 10000;     
        width: 35px;        
    }

    .page-sidebar-fixed.page-sidebar-hover-on .page-sidebar .selected {
        display: none;
    }

    .page-sidebar-fixed.page-sidebar-hover-on .page-content {
        margin-left: 35px;
    }
    .page-sidebar-fixed.page-sidebar-hover-on .footer {
        margin-left: 35px;
    }

    .page-sidebar-fixed .page-sidebar-closed .page-sidebar .sidebar-search .submit,
    .page-sidebar-fixed .page-sidebar .sidebar-toggler {
        -webkit-transition: all  0.2s ease;
         -moz-transition: all  0.2s ease;
           -o-transition: all  0.2s ease;
              transition: all  0.2s ease;
    }

    .page-sidebar-hovering {
        overflow: hidden !important;
    }

    .page-sidebar-hovering .sub-menu,
    .page-sidebar-hovering span.title,
    .page-sidebar-hovering span.arrow {       
        display: none !important;
    }

    .page-sidebar-hovering .submit {
        opacity: 0;
        width: 0 !important;
        height: 0 !important;
    }

    /***
    Page content
    ***/
    .page-content { 
        margin-left: 225px; 
        margin-top: 0px;
        min-height: 760px; 
    }

    .page-sidebar-fixed .page-content {
        min-height: 600px; 
    }

    .page-content.no-min-height {
        min-height: auto;
    }

    /***
    Footer
    ***/

    /* fixed sidebar */
    .page-sidebar-fixed .footer {
      margin-left: 225px;
      background-color: #fff;
    }

    .page-sidebar-fixed .footer .footer-inner {
      color: #333;
    }

    .page-sidebar-fixed.page-sidebar-closed .footer {
      margin-left: 35px;
    }

    .page-sidebar-fixed .footer .footer-tools .go-top { 
      background-color: #666;
    }

    .page-sidebar-fixed .footer .footer-tools .go-top i {
      color: #ddd;
    }

    /* boxed layout */
    .page-boxed .header .brand {
        margin-left: 0px !important;
        width: 226px;
    }

    .page-boxed .header .brand img {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
}

/***
For tablets and phones
***/
@media (max-width:979px) { 

    /***
    Body
    ***/
    body {
        margin: 0px !important;
    }   

    /***
    Page header
    ***/
    .header {
        margin: 0 !important;
    }

    .header .nav li.dropdown i {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        top:1px;
        right:0px;
    }

    .header .nav {
        margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    }

    .header .brand {
        margin-left: 0px !important;
        padding-left: 0px !important; 
    }

    .header .brand img {
        margin-left: 2px !important;
    }

    /***
    Page container
    ***/
    .page-container {
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
    }

    .page-header-fixed .page-container {
        margin-top: 0px !important;
    }

    /***
    Page content
    ***/
    .page-content {
        margin: 0px !important;
        padding: 0px !important;        
        min-height: 280px; 
    }

    /***
    Page sidebar
    ***/
    .page-sidebar {
        margin: 0 10px;
    }

    .page-sidebar.in {
        margin: 15px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 5;
    }

    .page-sidebar .sidebar-toggler {
        display: none;
    }

    .page-sidebar ul {
        margin-top:0px;
        width:100%;
    }

    .page-sidebar .selected {
        display: none !important;
    }

    .page-sidebar .sidebar-search {
      width: 220px;
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-bottom:20px;
    }

    /***
    Page title
    ***/
    .page-title {
        margin: 15px 0px;
    }

    /***
    Styler panel
    ***/
    .styler-panel {
        top:55px;
        right:20px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1280px) { 

    /***
    Form wizard
    ***/
    .form-wizard .step .desc {
      margin-top: 10px;
      display: block;
    }

    /***
    Pricing tables
    ***/

    .pricing-table .rate .price,
    .pricing-table2 .rate .price {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

} 

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { 

    /***
    Body
    ***/
    body {
        padding-top: 0px;
    }

    /***
    Page sidebar
    ***/
    .page-sidebar .btn-navbar.collapsed .arrow { 
        display: none;
    }   

    .page-sidebar .btn-navbar .arrow {
      position: absolute;
      right: 25px;
      width: 0; 
      height: 0;
      top:50px;
      border-bottom: 15px solid #5f646b;
      border-left: 15px solid transparent; 
      border-right: 15px solid transparent; 
    }

} 

@media (max-width: 767px) { 

    /***
    Page header
    ***/
    .header .navbar-inner .container-fluid,
    .header .navbar-inner .container {
        margin-left: 10px !important;
        margin-right: 10px !important;
    }

    .header .top-nav .nav{  
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }

    .header .nav > li > .dropdown-menu.notification:after, 
    .header .nav > li > .dropdown-menu.notification:before {
        margin-right: 180px;
    }

    .header .nav > li > .dropdown-menu.notification {
        margin-right: -180px;
    }

    .header .nav > li > .dropdown-menu.inbox:after, 
    .header .nav > li > .dropdown-menu.inbox:before {
        margin-right: 140px;
    }

    .header .nav > li > .dropdown-menu.inbox {
        margin-right: -140px;
    }

    .header .nav > li > .dropdown-menu.tasks:after, 
    .header .nav > li > .dropdown-menu.tasks:before {
        margin-right: 90px;
    }

    .header .nav > li > .dropdown-menu.tasks {
        margin-right: -90px;
    }

    /* Header logo */
    .header .brand {
        margin-left: 0px !important;
        width: 110px;
    }

    /***
    Page content
    ***/
    .page-content {
        padding: 10px !important;
    }

    /***
    Page title
    ***/
    .page-title {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    /***
    Styler pagel
    ***/
    .styler-panel {
        top:58px;
        right:12px;
    }   

    /***
    Page breadcrumb
    ***/
    .breadcrumb {
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }

    /***
    Portlet form action
    ***/
    .portlet-body.form .form-actions{
      padding-left: 15px;   
    } 

    /***
    Gritter notification
    ***/
    #gritter-notice-wrapper {
        right:1px !important;
    }

    /***
    Form input validation states
    ***/
    .input-icon .input-error, 
    .input-icon .input-warning, 
    .input-icon .input-success { 
        top:-27px;
        float: right;
        right:10px !important;
    }   

    /***
    Advance tables
    ***/
    .table-advance tr td.highlight:first-child a {
        margin-left: 8px;
    }

    /***
    Footer  
    ***/    
    .footer {
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;        
    }   

    .footer .go-top {  
        float: right;
        display: block;
        margin-right: 0px;
    }

    /***
    Vertical inline menu
    ***/
    .ver-inline-menu li.active:after {
        display: none;
    }

    /***
    Form controls
    ***/
    .form-horizontal .form-actions {
        padding-left: 180px;    
    }

    .portlet .form-horizontal .form-actions {
        padding-left: 190px;    
    }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {

    /***
    Header navbar
    ***/
    .header .nav {
        clear:both !important;
    }

    .header .nav > li.dropdown .dropdown-toggle {
        margin-top:3px !important;
    }   

    .header .nav li.dropdown .dropdown-toggle .badge {
        top: 11px;
    }

    /***
    Page sidebar
    ***/
    .page-sidebar.in {
        margin-top: 7px !important;
    }

    /***
    Styler panel
    ***/
    .styler-panel {
        top:92px;
        right:12px;
    }   

    /***
    Page title
    ***/
    .page-title small {
        display: block;
        clear: both;
    }

    /***
    Dashboard date range panel
    ***/
    .page-content .breadcrumb .dashboard-date-range  {
        padding-bottom: 8px;
    } 

    .page-content .breadcrumb .dashboard-date-range span {
        display: none;
    }

    /***
    Login page
    ***/
    .login .logo {
        margin-top:10px;
    }

    .login .content {
        padding: 30px; 
        width: 222px;
    }

    .login .content h3 {
        font-size: 22px;
    }

    .login .content .m-wrap {
        width: 180px;
    }

    .login .checkbox {
        font-size: 13px;
    }

    /***
    Form controls
    ***/    
    .form-horizontal.form-bordered .control-label {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        padding-top: 0;
        text-align: left;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    .form-horizontal.form-bordered .controls {
        padding-top: 0 !important;
        border-left: 0 !important;  
    }

    .form-horizontal.form-bordered.form-label-stripped .control-group:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: none !important;
    } 

    .form-horizontal.form-bordered.form-label-stripped .control-group:nth-child(even) .controls {
      background-color: none !important;  
    }

    .form-horizontal.form-row-seperated .control-label {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        padding-top: 0;
        text-align: left;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    .form-horizontal.form-row-seperated .controls {
        border-left: 0;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    .portlet .form-horizontal .form-actions {
        padding-left: 10px;     
    }

    /***
    Hidden phone
    ***/
    .hidden-480 {
        display: none;
    }

    /***
    Modal header close button fix
    ***/
    .modal-header .close {
        margin-top: 5px !important;
    }

    /***
    Fix text view
    ***/
    .control-group .controls .text {
        display: block !important;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {

    .header .nav > li.dropdown .dropdown-toggle {
      padding-left: 8px !important;
      padding-right: 8px !important;
    }

    /***
    Hidden phone
    ***/
    .hidden-320 {
        display: none;
    }

    .header .brand {
        width: 100px;
    }   
}
```

Comment: can u build a jsfiddle or a codepen plz ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the [MDN article on `min-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height)

> The min-height CSS property is used to set the minimum height of a
>   given element. It prevents the used value of the height property from
>   becoming smaller than the value specified for min-height.

Specifically- you need to also define the `height` when declaring `min-height`, as that is what `min-height` is calculated relative to.

> If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly
>   (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not
>   absolutely positioned, the percentage value is treated as 0.

The most common way to have content 100% of viewport height is to assign a height value of 100% to the `html` and `body` elements, then the main page 'container'. One other approach is to have an absolutely positioned element with a `top` and `bottom` setting of zero.